# An Error in my java database backup code

Tags: java, swing, backup, database-restore

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Backup extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String path = null;
    String filename;

    public Backup() {
        initComponents();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.showOpenDialog(this);
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd").format(new Date());
        try {
            File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
            path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            path = path.replace("\\", "/");
            path = path + " _ " + date + ".sql";
            jTextField5.setText(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Process p;
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = runtime.exec("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server5.1/bin/mysqldump.exe -u root -p123 --add-drop-database -B tsms -r" + path);
            int Processcomplete = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println("" + Processcomplete);
            if (Processcomplete == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Database Backup Successfully");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
            }
            jTextField5.setText(null);
            System.gc();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

I have developed a Java Swing Application with MySQL Server database and now I want to provide backup and restore option in my java swing application that is on click of a button.

It should backup the database and restore the database any possibilities this is my backup code. But when I run this code always `(Processcomplete == 2)`  what is the error in this code?

Comment: use `getErrorStream()` to read the error from process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code. I'll try to explain them all. But the first one is the biggest mistake which I see to return error code 2.

> **File names cannot contain special characters like `/`**.

One of the major problems I see in your code is the file name that you are trying to save. Windows does not allow `/` or `\` to be entered as file names. So adding `YYYY/MM/DD` to the file name is not a good idea.

> **Only one backup file per day**

By adding only the date you can create only one backup file per day the same file will be replaced when trying to get several backups in the same day. Use [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) of `util.Date` object to get a unique number which is being refreshed in every millisecond.

Replace this part;

```
try {
    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
    path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.replace("\\", "/");
    path = path + " _ " + new Date().getTime() + ".sql";
    jTextField5.setText(path);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both of the above mentioned problems are solved by this.

> **Giving the absolute path of `mysqldump.exe` is a bad idea**

Because in different computers it may change. You have given `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server5.1/bin/mysqldump.exe` as the path, instead add it as an Environment Variable after installing MySQL and just use `mysqldump.exe`.

```
p = runtime.exec("mysqldump.exe -u root -p123 --add-drop-database -B tsms -r" + path);
```

---

File naming part was the problem, it should work now.

Comment: File name was the problem.  Thumbs up!